# How to get the latest documents in collection and remove other

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to get the latest document in a collection (here is notifications) for each user and remove the other. Lets assume I have data like this:

```
[
    { user: 1, time: ISODate("Mon, 14 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 1, time: ISODate("Tue, 15 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 1, time: ISODate("Fri, 23 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 2, time: ISODate("Tue, 27 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 2, time: ISODate("Wed, 28 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 2, time: ISODate("Wed, 28 Sep 2015 07:33:16 +0000"), msg: "message" }
]
```

For example, l want to get the last 2 notifications and remove the other, so the result for `user 1` should be:

```
[
    { user: 1, time: ISODate("Tue, 15 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 1, time: ISODate("Fri, 23 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" }
]
```

And data will be like this:

```
[
    { user: 1, time: ISODate("Tue, 15 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 1, time: ISODate("Fri, 23 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 2, time: ISODate("Tue, 27 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 2, time: ISODate("Wed, 28 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" },
    { user: 2, time: ISODate("Wed, 28 Sep 2015 07:33:16 +0000"), msg: "message" }
]
```

and other records, which belong to `user 1`, will be removed.
So what is the efficient way to do that?

Comment: If I understand you want to update the documents in your collection and leave only last two for each user. right?

Comment: @user3100115 yes, that it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your documents look like this:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("562b38f9d6995d3311d9ddce"), "user" : 1, "time" : ISODate("2015-09-14T06:22:36Z"), "msg" : "message" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("562b38f9d6995d3311d9ddcf"), "user" : 1, "time" : ISODate("2015-09-15T06:22:36Z"), "msg" : "message" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("562b38f9d6995d3311d9ddd2"), "user" : 2, "time" : ISODate("2015-09-28T06:22:36Z"), "msg" : "message" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("562b38f9d6995d3311d9ddd3"), "user" : 2, "time" : ISODate("2015-09-28T07:33:16Z"), "msg" : "message" }
```

From [MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/) you can use the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/#exp._S_slice) operator to get only last two documents for each user

```js
var bulkOp = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$sort": { "user": 1, "time": -1 }}, 
    { "$group": { "_id": "$user", "times": { "$push": "$time" } }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "times": { 
            "$slice": [ "$times", 2 ]
        }
     }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulkOp.find({ 
        "user": doc._id, 
        "time": { "$nin": doc.times }
    }).remove();
    count++;
    if(count % 100 === 0) {
        //Execute per 100 operations and re-init 
        bulkOp.execute();
        bulkOp = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// Clean up queues
if(count > 0) {
    bulkOp.execute();
}
```

Prior to MongoDB 3.2 you need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your document by `user` then use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator which return array of `times`. From then you will need to loop through your aggregation result using the [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop then return the last two times by first [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)ing your `times` array in [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) order and using the [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method. You can then remove you document using the ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) operations for maximum efficiency. Of course the [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator let you filter out old documents.

```js
var bulkOp = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$user", 
        "times": { "$push": "$time" } 
    } }
]).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var times = doc.times.sort(function(t1, t2) { 
        return t1 < t2 ? -1 :  (t1 > t2 ? 1 : 0); 
    }).reverse().slice(-2);
    bulkOp.find({ 
        "user": doc._id, 
        "time": { "$nin": times }
    }).remove(); 
    count++; 
    if(count % 100 === 0) {  
        //Execute per 100 operations and re-init   
        bulkOp.execute();     
        bulkOp = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})

// Clean up queues
if(count > 0) { 
    bulkOp.execute(); 
}
```

Comment: After trying with about 3M records, this way is much better. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

use the following to find the last two

```
 db.collection.find({user:1}).sort({time:-1}).limit(2)
```

use the following to delete all documents except last two documents

```
var i = 0;
var user_ids = [];
db.users.find({user:1},{_id:1}).sort({time:-1}).forEach(function(user) {
    if(i>1)
    user_ids[i] = user._id;
   i++;
});
db.users.remove({_id: {$in: user_ids}})
```

There is no direct `method` to remove all the `document` except last two.
But if you want to remove only single `document` at a time then you can use `findAndModify` function by defining remove attribute and set it as `true`

Comment: Well, I know how to get these, but I don't know how to remove the other.

Comment: you want to delete all document after find or except last two

Comment: I want to remove documents which belong to `user 1` except the last two. Not delete all documents in collection.

Comment: Yes, in the example above, only this document `{ user: 1, time: ISODate("Mon, 14 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" }` should be removed.
And if I get documents from `user 2`, this document `{ user: 2, time: ISODate("Tue, 27 Sep 2015 06:22:36 +0000"), msg: "message" }` will be removed.

Comment: Code has been edited please check it(I wrote the code for mongo shell but you can convert it as you require)

Comment: @user 3100115 You are also looping in your answer

Comment: The problem is not the loop. but it's the wrong way to do this as I already said. For example what if you need to perform the same operation for all users in the collection?